# Array with each_by_index

Tags: ruby, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using a loop that will access the value of an array. I'm using `with_index` to correctly display the results, however, arrays start at 0, but my DB values start at 1. So, when the array is iterated, and it reaches, index #6 (position 7 in the array) it stops and, therefore, the value stored at the seventh field is not displayed. I could be wrong, but that's what I think is happening.

I read that it's possible to pass arguments to the `each_with_index` method, in case the starting value should be other than 0, but I can't find how to do it.

I'm relatively new to working with arrays, and relatively new to Ruby as a whole.

EDIT

```
<% @by_ticket.each_with_index do |ticketshead, id| %>
<% @tickets[id].id %>
<% end %>
```

The @by_ticket is a group_by statement at the controller. When i loop through it, it brings back all but the last record that meets the parameters. My question is how to start the loop at 1, instead of 0. I'll check the provided link by Hitham S. AlQadheeb.

EDIT to correct a typo in code's line 2. Thanks.

Comment: Please paste some sample code , the actual issue is not clear ..

Comment: Could you refine what exactly do you want? maybe you don't need to use this method at all if you work with db

Comment: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See http://SSCCE.org for guidance."

Comment: @tickets.id and just id that is passed to the block are not the same

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I think is just incrementing the index in the block like the following:

```
['a', 'b', 'c'].each_with_index { |item, index| puts "#{item} #{index + 1}" }
```

Comment: sorry, posted the answer before the update. It made some misunderstanding but I think my answer is useful for the original question

Comment: I've tried that Nickolay, but then it omits the first record on the DB. Maybe im far from right about the reason i think its happening. I have 7 records that i want to display, but the each loop only brings up 6. Its as if the length of the array is 6 instead of 7.

Comment: if each loop through 6 records that means that you've got just 6 records. Check your query first

Comment: I got it to work. Took the idea from the "duplicated answer" that i was provided with. I ended up doing it like this:

{<% (1..@by_ticket.length+1).each_with_index do |ticketscab, id| %>
 <% @tickets[id].id %>
 <% end %>}

Thanks everyone!